# Bride and Groom: King and Queen?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, marriage, malchut-royalty

I was at a wedding recently where a Rabbi spoke under the Chuppah and said that a groom is like a king and a bride is like a queen. I have heard these sayings a num er of times in the past. What is the source for this idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the earliest source is [Pirkei Derabbi Eliezer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirkei_de-Rabbi_Eliezer) [Chapter 16](http://www.shechem.org/torah/pdre/16.htm).

> החתן דומה למלך מה המלך הכל מקלסין אותו שבעת ימי המשתה כך חתן הכל מקלסין אותו שבעת ימי המשתה מה המלך לובש בגדי כבוד כך החתן לובש בגדי כבוד מה המלך שמחה ומשתה לפניו כל הימים כך החתן שמחה ומשתה לפניו כל שבעת ימים מה המלך אינו יוצא לשוק לבדו כך החתן אינו יוצא לשוק לבדו מה המלך פניו מאירות כאור החמה כך חתן פניו מאירות כאור החמה שנ' והוא כחתן יוצא מחופתו:‏
>   A groom is similar to a king: Just as a king everyone praises him for seven days of feasting, so too a groom everyone praises him for seven days of feasting; just as a king wears honorable clothing, so too a groom wears honorable clothing; just as a king has happiness and feasting before him all of the days, so too a groom has happiness and feasting before him all of seven days; just as a king does not go out to the market alone, so too a groom does not go out to the market alone; just as a king's face is bright like the sun, so too a groom's face is bright like the sun, as it says "and [the sun] is like a groom leaving his wedding-canopy" ([Psalms 19:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2619.htm#6)). (translation mine)

Comment: You are my hero. This only mentions the groom, but tbh I have only heard the term applied to a groom before, and the bride woukd be a queen by extension of the metaphor.

Comment: @BabySeal a queen consort, I guess, not a queen regnant.

Comment: What does the Pirkei De'Rabbi Eliezer base this on though?

Comment: @bondonk It's hard to say as there are so few rabbinic works which predate it.